# Looping through SimpleXMLElement to access attributes

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I am trying process data retrieved with SimpleXML and am having great difficulty.  I have read numerous threads here about this subject, they all LOOK like what I am doing, but mine are not working.  Here's what I've got:

```
<ROOT>
    <ROWS COMP_ID="165462">
    <ROWS COMP_ID="165463">
</ROOT>
```

My code:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('10.xml');
foreach( $xml->ROWS as $comp_row ) {
    $id = $comp_row->COMP_ID;
}
```

As I step through this in my debugger, I can see that $id is not set to the string value of COMP_ID, but becomes a SimpleXMLElement itself containing the CLASSNAME object.  I've tried many variations of addressing this attribute but none work, including $comp_row->attributes()->COMP_ID and others.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SimpleXML is an array-like object. Cheat sheet:

- **Unprefixed child elements** as numeric-index or traversable

  - Does not include prefixed elements (**NOTE**, I really mean *prefixed*, not *null-namespace*! `SimpleXMLElement` handling of namespaces is a strange and arguably broken.)
  - first child: `$sxe[0]`
  - new `SimpleXMLElement` with a subset of matching elements: `$sxe->ROWS`, `$sxe->{'ROWS'}`
  - iterate children: `foreach ($sxe as $e)`, `$sxe->children()`
  - Text content: `(string) $sxe`. `SimpleXMLElement` always returns another `SimpleXMLElement`, so if you need a string *cast it explicitly*!
- **Prefixed child elements**:

  - `$sxe->children('http://example.org')` returns a new `SimpleXMLElement` with elements 
    in the matching namespace, *with namespace stripped* so you can use it like the previous section.
- **Attributes in null namespace** as key-index:

  - specific attribute: `$sxe['attribute-name']
  - all attributes: `$sxe->attributes()`
  - `$sxe->attributes()` returns a special `SimpleXMLElement` that shows attributes as *both* child elements *and* attributes, so both the following work:
  - `$sxe->attributes()->COMP_ID`
  - `$a = $sxe->attributes(); $a['COMP_ID'];`
  - Value of an attribute: coerce to string `(string) $sxe['attr-name']`
- **Attributes in other namespaces**:

  - all attributes: `$sxe->attributes('http://example.org')`
  - specific attribute: `$sxe_attrs = $sxe->attributes('http://example.org'); $sxe_attrs['attr-name-without-prefix']`

What you want is:

```
$xml = '<ROOT><ROWS COMP_ID="165462"/><ROWS COMP_ID="165463"/></ROOT>';

$sxe = simplexml_load_string($xml);

foreach($sxe->ROWS as $row) {
    $id = (string) $row['COMP_ID'];
}
```

Comment: Bingo.  Forcing the data type did it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You're missing...

```
foreach( $xml->ROWS as $comp_row ) {
    foreach ($comp_row->attributes() as $attKey => $attValue) {
        // i.e., on first iteration: $attKey = 'COMP_ID', $attValue = '165462'
    }
}
```

[PHP Manual: SimpleXMLElement::attributes](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.attributes.php)

Comment: this is the answer for "how to loop through attributes"!