# XML-JSON content negotiation

Tags: php, xml, json

Im looking to only display certain things from pages like this: http://sc2ranks.com/api/psearch/am/MxGPezz/1t/division/Felanis%20Sierra?appKey=sentinelgaming.net . So far I am able to display something but its not even the correct number, using the php below. Can someone show me how I would display the "achivement-points" of this player from this XML web page?

```
$url = 'http://sc2ranks.com/api/psearch/am/MxGPezz/1t/division/Felanis%20Sierra?appKey=sentinelgaming.net';
$xml = file_get_contents($url);

echo $xml->achievement-points;
```

Thanks

Comment: `$xml = [{"achievement_points":580,"character_code":0,"team":{"points":1308,"wins":127,"losses":104,"division_id":351726,"division_name":"Division Felanis Sierra","id":12366704},"region":"us","bnet_id":2868603,"name":"MxGPezz","id":3416151}]' (length=233)` strange!

Comment: Not strange--the server is using content negotiation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The content-type of this file varies depending on the `Accept` header or the `format` query parameter. It seems you can retrieve at least XML or JSON.

The default you get from `file_get_contents()` will be JSON because it does not include an `Accept` request header, but the default from a browser will be XML because browsers usually include an XML mime type in their `Accept` request header.

To get JSON:

```
$url = 'http://sc2ranks.com/api/psearch/am/MxGPezz/1t/division/Felanis%20Sierra?appKey=sentinelgaming.net';

// &format=json is not strictly necessary,
// but it will give you fewer surprises
$json = file_get_contents($url.'&format=json');
$records = json_decode($json);
echo $records[0]->achievement_points, "\n";
```

To get XML:

```
$sxe = simplexml_load_file($url.'&format=xml');
echo (string) $sxe->record->{'achievement-points'}, "\n";
```

To use the `$sxe` object see [this SimpleXML cheat sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14421571/1002469).

Instead of using the `format` param you could set the `Accept` header. You can also add some abstraction to getting a url so that you can retrieve the content type and encoding as well. See example below.

```
function get_url($url, $context=null) {
    $response = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
    $ctypeheaders = preg_grep('/^Content-Type:\s/i', $http_response_header);
    $ctype = NULL;
    if ($ctypeheaders) {
        $ctype = end($ctypeheaders);
        $ctype = end(explode(':', $ctype, 2));
        $ctype = explode(';', $ctype, 2);
        $charset = isset($ctype[1]) ? $ctype[1] : '';
        if ($charset && preg_match('/charset\s*=\s*([^\s]+)/i', $charset, $matches)) {
            $charset = $matches[1];
        }
        $ctype[1] = $charset;
        $ctype = array_map('trim', $ctype);
    }
    return array($response, $ctype);
}
```

You can then use `get_url()` like so:

```
// With no accept header, just see what we get:
list($content, $contenttype) = get_url($url);
list($type, $encoding) = $contenttype;
// $type will be 'application/xml' or 'application/json'
// $encoding is very handy to know too

// Or we can specify an accept header:
$opt_accept_xml = stream_context_create(array(
    'http' => array(
        'header' => "Accept: application/xml\r\n"
    )
));

list($content, $contenttype) = get_url($url, $opt_accept_xml);
```

Comment: I can't get anything to display for that even thought I think this was a step in the right direction. Turns up blank no matter what variation I use with this method.

Comment: `file_get_contents()` is a string--you have to parse it. Also, this url returns json to PHP, not XML. See updated answer.

Comment: Oh my god, thank you so much Francis, I really appreciate it! First time I have seen it work from posting this question multiple times. Only answer that makes sense!

Comment: Does adding `'&format=xml'` fixes the problems in similar cases? I see it's a `nginx/0.8.53 + Phusion Passenger 3.0.1 (mod_rails/mod_rack)` Server

Comment: can we make `file_get_contents()` & `simplexml_load_file()` log HTTP headers when needed?

Comment: A 'format' parameter is a common convention, but you cannot depend on it. (I discovered it by guessing.) You can retrieve headers with the [`$http_response_header`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.httpresponseheader.php) magic variable or [`stream_get_meta_data()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-get-meta-data.php) if you have a stream resource. I expanded the answer with more options.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:

```
    echo $xml->record[0]->achievement-points;
```

Comment: For some reason that also comes up with "0" even though "0" is not the correct number of achivement-points for this user.