# Table formatting for xml returned via CURL from API

Tags: php, xml, curl, html-table

I am using another company's API to retrieve information from their database, it is being returned to me in XML format. I'm trying to accomplish two things - but am having a couple issues.

**1st** I would like to format the raw XML data into a table format, that will be easier to view via browser.

**2nd** The data I am receiving is IDs/usernames/passwords/emails. I would like to be able to import that data into my DB so that each userID is a row inserted into the DB (I can do the DB work, I just can't figure out how to process each user individually )

The API formatting is like this `<API> <message> <user> <id> </id> <login> </login> <password> </password> <message> </message> </API>` only there will be hundreds of user's instead of just one.

Whenever I just do a print of $array, I get the data as a big blob as intended. However, when I use the updated code, (below) I receive an error that user is not a valid index. I also receive what looks to be the start of my table, without any data in it (only borders).

If anyone could help me figure out why the table is not receiving data (or give me advice on a better way to do it) I would greatly appreciate it.

Extra points for anyone who can help me figure out number two.

Error is `Notice: Undefined index: user in /home/public_html/new/test.php on line 36` **line 36 is commented in the code**

Here is the bottom part of my code:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
// Method execution
$result = curl_exec($ch);
// Close CURL session

$array = json_decode(json_encode((array)simplexml_load_string($result)),1);

$array_user=$array['user']; //line 36

$tab='<table border="1" width="400">';
for ($j=1; $j< count($array_user) ; $j++) {

  $tab.='<tr>';
  $tab.='<td>'.$array_user[$j]['id'].'</td>';
  $tab.='<td>'.$array_user[$j]['login'].'</td>';
  $tab.='<td>'.$array_user[$j]['mail'].'</td>';
 $tab.='<td>'.$array_user[$j]['date'].'</td>';
 $tab.='</tr>';
}

$tab.='</table>';

echo $tab;


?>
```

Comment: your xml is broken, see the first `<message>`and the `<user>` nodes aren't closed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$sxe = simplexml_load_string('<API><message><user><id>10</id><login>a</login><password>abc</password></user><user><id>11</id><login>456</login><password>def</password></user></message></API>');

// or $sxe = simplexml_load_file($xml_url);

function tabulate(SimpleXMLElement $sxe) {
    if (!count($sxe)) return '';
    $table = "<table border='1' width='400'>\n";
    $header = false;
    foreach($sxe as $row) {
        if (!$header) {
            $table .= "<thead>\n<tr>\n\t";
            foreach ($row as $field) {
                $table .= "<th>";
                $table .= htmlspecialchars($field->getName(), ENT_NOQUOTES, 'UTF-8');
                $table .= "</th>";
            }
            $table .= "\n</tr>\n</thead>\n<tbody>\n";
            $header = true;
        }
        $table .= "<tr>\n\t";
        foreach ($row as $field) {
            $table .= "<td>";
            $table .= htmlspecialchars((string) $field, ENT_NOQUOTES, 'UTF-8');
            $table .= "</td>";
        }
        $table .= "\n</tr>\n";

    }
    $table .= "</tbody>\n</table>";
    return $table;
}


function insert_users(PDO $db, SimpleXMLElement $users) {
    $ins = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO users (id, login, password) VALUES (?,?,?)');
    foreach ($users as $user) {
        $userdata = array((string) $user->id, (string) $user->login, (string) $user->password);
        $ins->execute($userdata);
    }
}

insert_users($db, $sxe->message->user);

echo tabulate($sxe->message->user);
```

[`SimpleXMLElement` cheat sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14421571/1002469)

Comment: I love you. Thank you very much.

Comment: I also wanted to say that this works PERFECTLY, I really appreciated the help. If I could give you rep I would.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you loop through your XML using `simplexml`.
You can build a table or a query from this.

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($x); // XML is in $x

foreach ($xml->user as $user) {

    echo $user->id . ': ' . $user->login . ' : '
    echo $user->password . ' : ' . $user->message . '<br />;
}
```

see it working: http://codepad.viper-7.com/KhWsla

BTW: your xml needs repair:

```
<API>
    <user>
        <id>1</id>
        <login>michi</login>
        <password>12345</password>
        <message>hi!</message>
    </user>
</API>
```

Comment: So, something like this?

`$xml = simplexml_load_string($result); // XML is in $x

foreach ($xml->user as $user) {
 
 echo $user->id . ': ' . $user->login . ' : ' . $user->password . ' : ' . $user->message . '<br />';
}`

oh it is important to note - <message> is used to properly, they mean it is the message sent from the API, there is no <message> user data, it is simply a encloser like <api>

Comment: @RobertDickey: `foreach ($xml->message->user as $user)`